# Same command is not executed by Java, while directly in cmd.exe is working, how?

Tags: java, windows, cmd

I want to convert a wav audio file into flac with SOX and therefore I need to use the cmd (command prompt).

Weird thing is that the command is executed if I open manually the command prompt, but not when Java executed the code in cmd.exe. It receives

```
'sox' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I have written the following Java code to this:

```
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start cmd.exe /K \"cd C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Documents\\Mendix\\NativeMobile-main\\sox\\  "
                + "&& sox "  + UUID+".wav --channels=1 --bits=16 "+UUID+".flac"
                + "&& exit");
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        IOUtils.copy(p.getInputStream(), writer, "UTF-8");
        String theString = writer.toString();
```

So my question is, how is it possible that Java executed command is not recognized while executing manually is executed?

see attached file here https://ibb.co/kKtT3XH

Comment: Get rid of the `cd` and the `exit` and put the full path to the executable and to the input files in the command.

Comment: cd and exit dropped, still not working @thilo2